# Soap integration tests load only the tested endpoint not all Endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-test, spring-ws

I have a qustion: 
what would be the right configuraiton to load only the Enpoint class that I want to test in that integration test and not the full Application context (not All the Enpoint Classes)?
Right now I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {WebServiceConfigTest.class}, properties = {"application.address=http://hostname:port/context"})
public class MyEndpointTest {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;


@Before
public void init() {
    mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
@Test
public void test1(){}
....
}
```

in WebServiceConfigTest is:

```
@ComponentScan("mypackages.soap")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SoapApplication.class)
@MockBean(classes = {MyService.class})
public class WebServiceConfigTest {
}
```

SoapApplication is:

```
@ComponentScan({"mypackages"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SoapApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(SoapApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

The reason is that in Soap module I have a dependency of Service module which has other dependencies as well and so on. 
If i load the whole ApplicaitonContext then:

- either I need to mock the full list of services that I use in Soap module
- or to mock the underneath dependencies of Service module, such as DataSource, Queues etc.

If I do the second will make Soap module aware of things it should not be.
If I do the first I am forced to mock and maintain in the config test file the full list of used Services which can be long.

Any advices here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searches and trials i found the solution.
As you can ask Spring on REST to loaad only 1 Controller into the context with

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
```

the same thign you can do for Soap with

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyEndpoint.class})
```

It will load only the Endpoint you want and you can mock the the Services you use inside that or you can go all the way till the Repository o whatever your Application Bussiness logic is doing there.

Answer (score 1):

> what would be the right configuration to load only the Endpoint class that I want to test in that integration test and not the full Application context

you can ask spring to only instantiated particular `Controller` class but not loading complete application context by using [@WebMvcTest(MyEndpoint.class)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyEndpoint.class)
public class MyEndpointTest {

 @MockBean //mock all service beans that are injected into controller
 private Service service;

 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Test
   public void test1(){}
      ....
   }
}
```

I would also recommend in doing end to end integration testing using `@SpringBootTest` if you are using embedded database (for example H2), or embedded queues for testing

Comment: I this it works for RESTand i used it, but for Soap is working?